# Rights issue in DevOps and pipeline connection

Tags: npm, cypress, devops, npm-install

I'm trying to set up a DevOps pipeline on another server, where I have Cypress installed, which should take my new release and install it there and run the test. However, I get the following error:

`##[error]Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, stat '\\phasp13jm2\UICypress\.npmrc'`

[image]

Is this a setting and rights issue in DevOps itself or is there a problem elsewhere?

Comment: Could you share some more details and code? Just looking at the error message with the .npmrc file, I would guess that you are using Azure Artifacts or another kind of private registry and probably missing permissions to install dependencies from a private library?

Comment: Problem solved. In the end, it was insufficient user rights in Devops to that testing machine.